# Simple Pygame animation stuttering

Tags: python, pygame

I have a simple bouncing box window that was drawn with 'Pygame'. Everything seems to work properly, except for a little annoyance. It stutters constantly! I have no idea what could be causing the stutter. I thought it might be a delay, so I implemented a fixed time-step to allow the loop to catch up, but this had no effect.

```py
#--- initialize pygame window ---#
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
size = (1200,500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE)
fps = 60

#--- define color palette ---#
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

#--- define the player ---#
class player:
    def __init__(self,screen,surface, color):
        self.speed = 3
        self.direction_x = 1
        self.direction_y = 1
        self.screen = screen
        self.surface = surface
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.color = color
    def set_pos(self, x,y):
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
    def advance_pos(self):
        screen_width, screen_height = screen.get_size()
        if self.rect.x + self.rect.width > screen_width or player1.rect.x < 0:
            player1.direction_x *= -1
            player1.speed = 3
        elif player1.rect.y + player1.rect.height > screen_height or player1.rect.y < 0:
            player1.direction_y *= -1
            player1.speed = 3
        else:
            player1.speed -= 0.001
        self.rect.x += self.speed * self.direction_x
        self.rect.y += self.speed * self.direction_y
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, [0,0,self.rect.width,self.rect.height])
    def blit(self):
        screen.blit(self.surface, self.rect)
player1 = player(screen, pygame.Surface((50,50)), white)
player1.set_pos(50,50)
player1.draw()

#--- define game variables ---#
previous = time.time() * 1000
lag = 0.0
background = black
done = False

#--- game ---#
while not done:

    #--- update time step ---#
    current = time.time() * 1000
    elapsed = current - previous
    lag += elapsed
    previous = current

    #--- process events ---#
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
            break
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)

    #--- update logic ---#

    while True:
        player1.advance_pos()
        lag -= fps
        if lag <= fps:
            break

    #--- draw to screen ---#
    screen.fill(background)
    player1.blit()
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(fps)
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102586/locking-the-frame-rate-in-pygame) link? The answer provided there has some useful suggestions. If you need exactly 60 fps, you need vsync, which I am not sure pygame provides unless you use something like pyopengl for your pygame rendering.

Comment: I didn't know about PyOpenGL. Thanks!

Comment: Learning OpenGL from scratch can be pretty challenging if you have not worked with it before. If it would help, I could post a demo that replicates what you have already written using pygame and pyopengl.

Comment: that would be fantastic

Comment: I ran your code but didn't experience any noticeable stuttering. What FPS are you getting? If it's running at 60 fps there shouldn't be any visible stuttering. I would also recommend making a clock variable such as `clock = pygame.time.Clock()` then call `clock.tick(fps)` rather than your last line, which makes a new clock object every frame.

Comment: that didn't work. I think this is a shortcoming of the Pygame engine, and PyOpenGL seems to run smoothly. I would like to learn OpenGL anyways, so that's going to be the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rewrite of your code that uses opengl instead for the rendering. The major changes are as follows:

1. I used opengl immediate mode, which is out-of-date and deprecated, but is a lot easier to understand at first. Most of the gl calls are either in the player.draw() method or in the main loop.
2. I fixed the way the timer is done. Rather than doing just clock.tick(fps), I manually keep track of the amount of time that it takes to do all of the processing to the frame and add the appropriate millisecond delay to reach 60 fps. You can try that modification with your existing pygame code before migrating to opengl as that might be sufficient to remove most of the stutter.

   ```
   import pygame
   import time
   from OpenGL.GL import *

   class Player:
       def __init__(self, screen, width, height, color):
           self.x = 0
           self.y = 0
           self.speed = 3
           self.direction_x = 1
           self.direction_y = 1
           self.screen = screen
           self.width = width
           self.height = height
           self.color = color

       def set_pos(self, x, y):
           self.x = x
           self.y = y

       def advance_pos(self):
           screen_width, screen_height = screen.get_size()
           if self.x + self.width > screen_width or self.x < 0:
               self.direction_x *= -1
               self.speed = 3
           elif self.y + self.height > screen_height or self.y < 0:
               self.direction_y *= -1
               self.speed = 3
           else:
               self.speed -= 0.001
           self.x += self.speed * self.direction_x
           self.y += self.speed * self.direction_y

       def draw(self):
           glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
           glLoadIdentity()
           glTranslate(self.x, self.y, 0)
           glBegin(GL_QUADS)
           glColor(*self.color)
           glVertex(0, 0, 0)
           glVertex(self.width, 0, 0)
           glVertex(self.width, self.height, 0)
           glVertex(0, self.height, 0)
           glEnd()

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       pygame.init()
       size = width, height = (550, 400)
       screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL)
       fps = 60
       black = (0,0,0,255)
       white = (255,255,255,255)

       player1 = Player(screen, 50, 50, white)
       player1.set_pos(50,50)

       done = False
       previous = time.time() * 1000
       glClearColor(*black)
       glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
       glLoadIdentity()
       glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1)
       clock = pygame.time.Clock()

       while not done:
           current = time.time() * 1000
           elapsed = current - previous
           previous = current
           delay = 1000.0/fps - elapsed
           delay = max(int(delay), 0)

           for event in pygame.event.get():
               if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                   done = True
                   break
               if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
                   size = width, height = event.w, event.h
                   screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL)
                   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
                   glLoadIdentity()
                   glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1)
                   glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

                   #reset player movement and position to avoid glitches where player is trapped outside new window borders
                   player1.set_pos(50, 50)
                   player1.direction_x = 1
                   player1.direction_y = 1

           player1.advance_pos()
           glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
           glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
           player1.draw()
           pygame.display.flip()
           pygame.time.delay(delay)
   ```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your help. OpenGL is going to be a lot of fun.

Answer (score 0):

I created a clock object befor entering the "while not done" loop and had no more lags

```py
#--- initialize pygame window ---#
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
size = (1200,500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE)
fps = 60

#--- define color palette ---#
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

#--- define the player ---#
class player:
    def __init__(self,screen,surface, color):
        self.speed = 3
        self.direction_x = 1
        self.direction_y = 1
        self.screen = screen
        self.surface = surface
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.color = color
    def set_pos(self, x,y):
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
    def advance_pos(self):
        screen_width, screen_height = screen.get_size()
        if self.rect.x + self.rect.width > screen_width or player1.rect.x < 0:
            player1.direction_x *= -1
            player1.speed = 3
        elif player1.rect.y + player1.rect.height > screen_height or player1.rect.y < 0:
            player1.direction_y *= -1
            player1.speed = 3
        else:
            player1.speed -= 0.001
        self.rect.x += self.speed * self.direction_x
        self.rect.y += self.speed * self.direction_y
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, [0,0,self.rect.width,self.rect.height])
    def blit(self):
        screen.blit(self.surface, self.rect)
player1 = player(screen, pygame.Surface((50,50)), white)
player1.set_pos(50,50)
player1.draw()

#--- define game variables ---#
previous = time.time() * 1000
lag = 0.0
background = black
done = False
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

#--- game ---#
while not done:

    #--- update time step ---#
    current = time.time() * 1000
    elapsed = current - previous
    lag += elapsed
    previous = current

    #--- process events ---#
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
            break
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)

    #--- update logic ---#

    while True:
        player1.advance_pos()
        lag -= fps
        if lag <= fps:
            break

    #--- draw to screen ---#
    screen.fill(background)
    player1.blit()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix is:

Pygame uses only integers to calculate the position of the Rect object,
what I did down here, I added a new object variable that saves the position as float, and then we pass it to the Rect position to round it up.

```
    self.x += self.speed * self.direction_x
    self.y += self.speed * self.direction_y
    self.rect.x = self.x
    self.rect.y = self.y
```

There is still some small jittering, but this is the smoothest we can get from pure Pygame Rects. I also moved the `pygame.time.Clock()` to a constant of `CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock().tick(fps)` outside from the game loop. And then call it inside the loop at the end of it, `CLOCK.tick(fps)`

```
#--- initialize pygame window ---#
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
size = (1200,500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE)
fps = 60

#--- define color palette ---#
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

#--- define the player ---#
class player:
    def __init__(self,screen,surface, color):
        self.speed = 3
        self.direction_x = 1
        self.direction_y = 1
        self.screen = screen
        self.surface = surface
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.color = color
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
    def set_pos(self, x,y):
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
    def advance_pos(self):
        screen_width, screen_height = screen.get_size()
        if self.rect.x + self.rect.width > screen_width or player1.rect.x < 0:
            player1.direction_x *= -1
            player1.speed = 3
        elif player1.rect.y + player1.rect.height > screen_height or player1.rect.y < 0:
            player1.direction_y *= -1
            player1.speed = 3
        else:
            player1.speed -= 0.001

        self.x += self.speed * self.direction_x
        self.y += self.speed * self.direction_y
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, [0,0,self.rect.width,self.rect.height])
    def blit(self):
        screen.blit(self.surface, self.rect)
player1 = player(screen, pygame.Surface((50,50)), white)
player1.set_pos(50,50)
player1.draw()

#--- define game variables ---#
previous = time.time() * 1000
lag = 0.0
background = black
done = False
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

#--- game ---#
while not done:

    #--- update time step ---#
    current = time.time() * 1000
    elapsed = current - previous
    lag += elapsed
    previous = current

    #--- process events ---#
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
            break
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)

    #--- update logic ---#

    while True:
        player1.advance_pos()
        lag -= fps
        if lag <= fps:
            break

    #--- draw to screen ---#
    screen.fill(background)
    player1.blit()
    pygame.display.update()
    CLOCK.tick(fps)
```