# pygame - Player creating bullets causes noticable FPS drops

Tags: python, pygame

I need my game to be capable of handling hundreds of bullets on screen. While the game seems not to have large slowdowns with smaller amounts of bullets (under 50 or so), it nonetheless does have them, and the problem becomes even more pronounced when around 100-200 are on the screen at the same time. This raised a particular concern I had: I want enemies to fire massive amounts of bullets aswell, but if the player's projectiles already cause such slowdowns, then there is no way that that will be possible.

Before I begin showing the code in question:

- I'm using pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.6)
- I use convert_alpha() on every image I load
- I use dirty sprites for the player, bullet, enemy and HUD classes and a pygame.sprite.LayeredDirty() group to store all sprites currently in-game; enemies, bullets and the HUD have additional pygame.sprite.Group()s for collision detection (for enemies and bullets) and reordering the sprites to render on top of everything (for the HUD). This seems to have improved the performance, but massive amounts of bullets still cause slowdowns
- I use PyCharm as my IDE

I'm pretty fresh to programming and I am not very certain what exactly causes the issue, so I will try to provide as much relevant code as possible. I will provide more if none of the culprits seem to be the causes of the issue. I apologize in advance if this is not enough information.

The slowdown gets ridiculous mostly with a debug superweapon I'm using, though it is sometimes noticable even when not nearly as many bullets are spawned (28 or a bit more) when I have many apps opened. This is a very small game so far, however, so I don't exactly understand why.

```
def init_player_weapon_level(self):
    # debug mode
    if self.lev_weapon == -1:
        self.set_weapon_values(100, 5, 100, True)
        self.firing_pattern = [[self.bullet_images["blue"], 0, 0, 90, -24],
                               [self.bullet_images["blue"], 0, 0, 92, -24],
                               [self.bullet_images["blue"], 0, 0, 88, -24],
                               ...]
...
```

The firing pattern list defined in this function is used below. It's very long. This list is replaced based on the player's weapon level, -1 being the highest. This function is called only when the player object is created or when it's manually initiated with a keypress.

```
def fire(self, now):
    if self.check_firing_conditions(now):
        self.last_shot = now
        for o in self.firing_pattern:
            bullet = PlayerBullet01(o[0], self.rect.centerx + o[1], self.rect.top + o[2], o[3], o[4])
            all_sprites.add(bullet)
            bullets.add(bullet)
            self.generate_heat(now)
```

This is the function responsible for firing weapons. It creates as many bullet objects as there are lists of parameters in `self.firing_pattern`, with an image [0], X [1] and Y [2] spawn offsets (which are then added or subtracted from the player's position to give an illusion that they're fired from the ship's cannons), angle [3] at which the bullet is fired (90 degrees is straight up) and speed [4] at which it traverses (it's negative in the firing patterns because the bullet moves upwards).
Since `self.firing_pattern` has 35 lists of parameters in it (which I omitted as that takes up space), 35 bullets are created all at once, fired with a delay of 100 milliseconds between the shots if the player presses the fire key. This makes exactly 245 bullets appear on the screen before the player's weapon overheats, which causes the weapon to stop firing. It is a lot, but the slowdown seems to be caused when there's already some bullets on the screen.

```
class PlayerBullet01(pygame.sprite.DirtySprite):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y, deg, speed):
        pygame.sprite.DirtySprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.center = self.rect.center

        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y)

        self.speed_mod = 0.065
        # deg - 90 because we don't want to rotate the image
        # by the amount of degrees it's supposed to face,
        # we want to rotate it by a much smaller amount
        # we also want to rotate it only once
        # since player bullets probably shouldn't follow
        # any other movement patterns than going straight to the target
        if deg != 0:
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, -deg + 90)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = self.center

        # we only want the bullet to move in a particular direction at a particular speed
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.direction += self.move(deg, speed)

        # spawn bullet at the center of the spaceship
        self.rect.centerx = self.position.x
        self.rect.bottom = self.position.y

    def update(self):
        self.dirty = 1
        self.position.x += self.direction.x * self.speed_mod * x_clock.delay
        self.position.y += self.direction.y * self.speed_mod * x_clock.delay
        self.rect.center = (self.position.x, self.position.y)

        # die if out of bounds
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()

    def move(self, degrees, offset):
        rads = math.radians(degrees)
        x = math.cos(rads) * offset
        y = math.sin(rads) * offset
        return x, y
```

This is the bullet class. I thought at first that the `move` function being called during every update slowed down the game (which is in an earlier version of the code, not shown here), but nothing has actually changed.

```
    hits_enemy = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(enemies, bullets, True, True)
    for hit in hits_enemy:
        create_generic_enemy(GFX_ENEMY)
```

Finally, this is the line that checks for collisions between the bullets and enemies (of which there are always only 10 on the screen). I disabled collisions for bullets and enemies and it still did not seem to have improved the performance of the game at all.

```
dirtyupdate = all_sprites.draw(screen)
pygame.display.update(dirtyupdate)
```

Oh, and this is how the game draws everything on screen in the main game loop.

Last possible culprit:
I found a way on Stack Overflow to stop pygame from micro-stuttering. It's a very annoying issue that seemed to happen for no reason whatsoever. It requires using a custom clock. I introduced this code to my game from here: [Simple Pygame animation stuttering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836374/simple-pygame-animation-stuttering)

```
previous = time.time() * 1000

# this is so it's easy to get out of the game loop
# (you just set GAME_RUNNING to false)
GAME_RUNNING = True
while GAME_RUNNING:
    # CLOCK
    # a pretty advanced clock that stops pygame from stuttering like a -----
    current = time.time() * 1000
    elapsed = current - previous
    previous = current
    x_clock.delay = 1000.0 / MAX_FPS - elapsed
    x_clock.delay = max(int(x_clock.delay), 0)

    ...

    # delays the game by delay
    # using pygame.time.wait() instead of pygame.time.delay()
    # because pygame.time.delay() makes my system fan go -------
    pygame.time.wait(x_clock.delay)
```

For the record, `delay` from the `x_clock` file is imported to class files, too. This is because it's required for these classes to adjust their movement to FPS drops. I don't believe this code is what causes the lag, but I remember that when I used pygame.time.delay() instead of wait(), my fan went nuts.

What causes this slowdown and how do I fix it? I have considered a few possibilities already (one of which may be Pygame not being able to handle this many projectiles), but I have already seen a game where a similar amount of bullets was consistently created on screen and it did not have any slowdowns whatsoever. I couldn't figure it out after looking at that game's code, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is actually the source of the slowdown but the following might work:

use `pygame.time.Clock()` as your timer. the `clock.tick(framerate)` (or `clock.tick_busy_loop(framerate)` which according to the documentation is more precise) will cap the maximal framerate. `clock.get_time()` will get you the time in miliseconds between the last two call of `clock.tick()` / `clock.tick_busy_loop()`.

Edit:

1 this is a more efficient `__init__` method:

```py
class PlayerBullet01(pygame.sprite.DirtySprite):
    images = {}
    for color in ['blue']:  # and your other bullet colors
        color_dict = {}
        for angle in range(360):
            img = pygame.transform.rotate(bullet_images[color], angle)
            color_dict[angle] = img, img.get_rect()
        images[color] = color_dict

    def __init__(self, color, x, y, deg, speed):
        pygame.sprite.DirtySprite.__init__(self)

        self.image, self.rect = self.images[color][deg]

        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y)

        self.speed_mod = 0.065
        # deg - 90 because we don't want to rotate the image
        # by the amount of degrees it's supposed to face,
        # we want to rotate it by a much smaller amount
        # we also want to rotate it only once
        # since player bullets probably shouldn't follow
        # any other movement patterns than going straight to the target

        # this code is now unnecessary

        # we only want the bullet to move in a particular direction at a particular speed
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.direction += self.move(deg, speed)

        # spawn bullet at the center of the spaceship
        self.rect.centerx = self.position.x
        self.rect.bottom = self.position.y
```

by preloading the rotated images it doesn't need to be done 35 times every time the player fires.

2 use the following script to get the runtime of your functions:

```py
from time import time


def timed(name):
    func_timer = FunctionTimer(name)

    def decorator(func):

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            start_time = time()
            return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            func_timer.add_time((time() - start_time) * 1000)
            return return_value

        return wrapper

    return decorator


class FunctionTimer:
    all = []
    old_time = time()
    frame_time = 0

    @classmethod
    def get_frame_summary(cls):
        new_time = time()
        cls.frame_time = new_time - cls.old_time
        cls.old_time = new_time
        print(f'------------------------------\n'
              f'FRAME TIME SUMMARY:\n'
              f'total frame time: {cls.frame_time * 1000:.5}\n'
              f'calls:\n'
              f'name                  calls  average     min         max         total')
        for t in sorted(cls.all, key=lambda x: x.avg_time, reverse=True):
            if len(t.frame_list):
                print(t)

        for t in cls.all:
            t.clear()

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.frame_list = []
        self.frame_calls = 0
        self.total = 0
        self.min = 0
        self.max = 0
        self.avg = 0
        self.all.append(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.name: <20}  {self.frame_calls: <5}  {self.avg_time: <10.5}  ' \
               f'{self.min_time: <10.5}  {self.max_time: <10.5}  {self.total_time: <10.5}'

    def add_time(self, added_time):
        self.frame_list.append(added_time)
        self.frame_calls += 1

    def clear(self):
        self.frame_list = []
        self.frame_calls = 0

    @property
    def min_time(self):
        self.min = min(self.frame_list)
        return self.min

    @property
    def max_time(self):
        self.max = max(self.frame_list)
        return self.max

    @property
    def avg_time(self):
        try:
            self.avg = sum(self.frame_list) / self.frame_calls
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            self.avg = 0
        return self.avg

    @property
    def total_time(self):
        self.total = sum(self.frame_list)
        return self.total
```

usage:

```py
@timed('name of the function')
def function(...):
    ...
```

put the timed decorator before any function you want to time.
call

```py
 FunctionTimer.get_frame_summary()
```

once in the main loop.
output:

```
------------------------------
FRAME TIME SUMMARY:
total frame time: [total time during this frame in ms]
calls:
name                  calls  average     min         max         total
[name of the function = parameter you passed into the decorator]  
[amount of times this function was called]  
[average runtime of the function, the output will be sorted by this value]
[minimal runtime]
[maximal runtime]
[total time spent in function (sum of all function call times)]
-- all functions that have been called will print this summary
sorted by their average runtime (descending) --
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question. Did you put the answer here by mistake? Please correct that and put the answer to the question where it belongs.

Comment: I used this clock before. The pygame clock causes a lot of annoying micro-stuttering that I mentioned above. However, using this clock actually DOES seem to solve the issue with lag!

It seems the custom clock may be the closest thing to the culprit. However, I don't really want to use the pygame one. You can notice tiny stutters while it's in use and that is pretty horrid. I'll probably have to ask a question similar to the one I provided the link to, but aimed at my game.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, anyway! It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it seems to work. I'll wait for some time, but if I don't get one that's more satisfying, I'll just go with yours and try to figure out how to get rid of the stutters.

Comment: @Rabbid76 i don't see what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: @Ox0zOrwa I just updated the answer to (hopefully) solve both problems.

Comment: @Kesslwovv I think you didn't understand the question. Please read the second sentence: *"While the game seems not to have large slowdowns with smaller amounts of bullets (under 50 or so), it nonetheless does have them, and the problem becomes even more pronounced when around 100-200"*. Therefore, the game lags if too many sprites are drawn. It is not a timing problem, it is a performance problem.

Comment: @Kesslwovv I don't think either of you are wrong, actually. While it is true that it's not the timing problem, switching from the custom clock to the pygame clock seems to have removed the lag caused by the bullets' presence. It didn't remove the completely arbitrary stutters, however, which is the reason why I was using the custom clock to begin with.

Oh, also: the edit did not really solve the issue, either. The stutters are not caused in the MOVEMENT of the player or anything. It's random frame drops for everything on screen that last like a millisecond, but are painfully noticable.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, however. Now it seems more obvious that it's relevant to the custom clock, it seems. I didn't think of that before, but I still don't really have any idea if there's a way to use that custom clock without causing everything on screen to go into a meltdown.

Comment: i have an idea about that as well but i need the following questions answered: 1. does _fired with a delay of 100 milliseconds_ mean that the player can only press the fire key every 100 ms or does this mean that all bullets in a burst are fired 1 each 100 ms 2. does the frame drop occur whenever you fire shots or just randomly?

Comment: @Kesslwovv
1 - When the player holds down the fire key, if the delay between the current and last invocation of the fire function is >= 100 milliseconds, all bullets in the firing pattern will be fired at once. You can hold the key as long as you like, but the bullets will only be fired after that time has passed.

Comment: 2 - When I use the custom clock, the framerate drastically decreases as more bullets are on screen - it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the creation of bullets itself. When I use the pygame clock, nothing like that happens at all. However, I get tiny stutters that are seemingly irrelevant to anything. It's not a huge problem - it doesn't affect the game logic at all. It just looks really ugly when you have random frame hops for whatever reason. And in a video game, that's pretty bad.

Comment: thanks. i actually expected your `PlayerBullet01.__init__` method to cause the lags because this can be done more efficient. I'll update my answer to include that more efficient method and a time-debug script.

Comment: @Kesslwovv aight I'll check it soon
I didn't even KNOW you can preload things, though!

Comment: @Kesslwovv Here's the result: on average, the frame calls seem to last 16-17 ms. And by that, I mean nothing in-between. The function doesn't always pick up when a "stutter" occurs, but when it does, it prints that the last frame call lasted 14 ms, sometimes even lower. I think that made me reconsider using Pygame: I genuinely appreciate your help on the matter, but I've already had a couple issues with it, such as the fact that when I tried to turn my game into an executable file, the file then complained because I used pygame's system fonts to create a font (which it couldn't read).

Comment: Which is strange, because the script worked just fine until I turned it into an executable, which made me come to the conclusion that it was Pygame causing that. Which seemed to be the case when I checked the exact same issue on their Github. I figured it out somehow (and solved lots of other issues I encountered on the way), but I'm not sure now... maybe it's not really worth going through the pain of using something like that and maybe I'll be better off using an actual game engine. What do you think?

Comment: @Ox0zOwra preloading things can help speed up your program - not just with pygame. e.g. if your program uses a lot of sin waves it is a good idea to pre-load those values into a list or dict so you don't have to call sin() every single time (costs time). For the timing library i sent you is more of a debugging tool; i don't understand why it would print less time on a "stutter". I have never used system fonts on my programs - at least not on those that i turned into an executable - so i can't say anything about that.

Comment: I am just a teenager whose hobby is programming for 1/2 year now, who has learnt programming from youtube tutorials and whose only public project is a [2d platformer made for a game jam](https://kesslwovv.itch.io/alakajam12-beta) so my opinion is probably not too founded. Anyways: If you want to use pygame or a game engine depends on what you want to achieve. If your only goal is to create games, game engines are clearly the better choice. if you want to learn something along the way, i would still recommend using pygame.

Comment: If you want a more professional opinion i would recommend checking out DaFluffyPotato ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYNrBrBOgTfHswcz2DdZQFA) / [website](https://dafluffypotato.com) / [discord](https://discord.gg/9Qt2GxF)) who is an actual python / pygame game developer. I would especially recommend his video on [pygame performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnKocNdF9-U), [why i'm glad i didn't use a game engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBaCRp9UzDw) and [why i'm **still** glad i didn't use a game engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TELHwCtvfFA)